# C++ pointer casting not working

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, casting

What am I doing wrong, the values in the message boxes are different. This is in a 32 bit app on windows. Everything that I've read says that reinterpret_cast shouldn't be necessary, even when I try it it still doesn't work. Also tried larger data types to hold the pointer but on 32 bit int or DWORD should be fine from what I've read.

```
A* a_ptr;    

DWORD a_ptr_address = (DWORD)a_ptr;
A* a_recasted_ptr = (A*)a_ptr_address;

//Display Result
char debugString[20];
snprintf(debugString, 20, "%08x", &a_ptr);
MessageBox(NULL, (const char*)debugString, NULL, NULL);
snprintf(debugString, 20, "%08x", &a_recasted_ptr);
MessageBox(NULL, (const char*)debugString, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: First off, `a_ptr` points to garbage so that's already UB.

Comment: You print pointers to pointers, no pointers itselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying the address of two different variables, a_ptr and a_recasted_ptr. They are not located at the same address memory.
Remove the `&` in the `snprintf()` call, and you're done.

Still, the code is awful...
Try this one:

```
A a;
A* a_ptr=&a;

SIZE_T a_ptr_address = (SIZE_T)a_ptr;
A* a_recasted_ptr = (A*)a_ptr_address;

//Display Result
char debugString[20];
snprintf(debugString, 20, "%0p", a_ptr);
MessageBoxA(NULL, debugString, NULL, NULL);
snprintf(debugString, 20, "%0p", a_recasted_ptr);
MessageBoxA(NULL, debugString, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: So this works, thank you. Sorry about the awful code, I had rewritten in many times trying to get it to work and it got pretty hacky.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace MessageBox with MessageBoxA and remove (const char*) cast.
2. In this example, you have 3 different variables: a_ptr, a_ptr_address and a_recasted_ptr.
   Since you have 3 variables, they have DIFFERENT addresses, because they are different variables. However, their value can be the same.
   For example, a_ptr and a_recasted_ptr have different addresses, but the same value.
   In your example, You are displaying the addresses of the variable, but not their values.

Fixed possible version:

```
struct A {};
// assign some dummy value to a_ptr
A* a_ptr = (A*)0x00000007;

DWORD_PTR a_ptr_address = (DWORD_PTR)a_ptr;
A* a_recasted_ptr = (A*)a_ptr_address;

//Display Result
char debugString[40];
sprintf_s(debugString, "Value of %08x=%u", &a_ptr, (DWORD_PTR)a_ptr);
MessageBoxA(NULL, debugString, NULL, NULL);
sprintf_s(debugString, "Value of %08x=%u", &a_recasted_ptr, (DWORD_PTR)a_recasted_ptr);
MessageBoxA(NULL, debugString, NULL, NULL);
```

edit: fixed errors according to comments

Comment: Not the dv, but this would produce compile errors, you might want to check it over.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that DWORD is not necessarily big enough to hold a pointer.  The OP probably needs to be using DWORD_PTR.